# How to check for stratified points?

Tags: correlation, data-mining

I originally posted this question on MathExchange but did not receive any answer.
I have discovered now this site dedicated to data mining, and think it is a more appropriate site to ask this.

In $\mathbb{R^3}$, we are given a list of $N$ (>>3) points.
It is presumed that they are "stratified" onto a few ($ < N/3$) planes, and a plot of the points sustains that (as e.g., in the attached ).

[image: Stratified_Points]
Of course, any triple of points will lie on a plane, but the question is to determine the minimum number of planes containing the points.
We could stack the points as rows in a matrix, add a final column of ones, look for the minors that have rank $3$ or less,
and find the relevant nullspace.
Aiming to find a more "systematic" approach, I tried with various decompositions of the matrix but did not find anything satisfactory.
Therefore the question is: is there a way to find a permutation of the rows of the matrix that divides it into blocks of lower rank ?
Or any other method to find the "preferential orientation" of the points. In case that the points can be reduced to rationals / integers, is the LLL algorithm doing the job ?
Hints in this respect are appreciated.

Comment: Since you refer to "data mining," do you conceive of these points as being measured with error or otherwise potentially varying a little around their "true" locations?  If not, then you have a very challenging combinatorial optimization problem but it's not one that appears to be relevant to statistics or data mining.  If so, then there may be attractive approaches (at least in theory), such as 3D versions of Hough transforms.

Comment: @whuber: thanks for your precisations. Well I am curious to know in both cases (with and without error), and also why the approach in  case of error does /does not intimately relate to the "precise" case. That is, I am interested to get a panoramical knowledge of the possible approaches to this problem.

Comment: @whuber: I came to learn now that the answer to my question lies in the SVD decomposition .